# Parser XML to ListView (use 2 classes)

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes, MainActivity and ZapisMainMenu, and i make an object of second class

```
public class ZapisMainMenu {

    public ArrayList<String> listZapis;

    public Context mContext; ///Используем Context, для того, 
                             ///чтобы использовать базовые функции приложения
    public XmlPullParser parser = mContext.getResources().getXml(R.xml.file);
                            ///Создаем парсер

    public void zapis() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {     ///метод для записи данных в ArrayList
        while (parser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equals("nameMainCategory")) {
                listZapis.add( parser.getAttributeValue(0));
            }
            parser.next();
        }
        MainActivity.list = listZapis;
    }
}







 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  ///ArrayList для отображения главных категорий

    ZapisMainMenu zapisMainMenuObject = new ZapisMainMenu();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
       ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       try {
        zapisMainMenuObject.zapis();         
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
       lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

But i have an error then make object zapisMainMenu, what whe problem?
I need a parser Xml to listView. I use xmlPull parser
But i have an error then make object zapisMainMenu, what whe problem?
I need a parser Xml to listView. I use xmlPull parser

Comment: instead of assign value to MainActivity List just make setter getter in ZapisMainMenu for listZapis list.

Comment: Thank you! but why i have an error, then make object?

Comment: what type of error have you getting ?

Comment: I can't understand your first answer, i need to start void zapis() in my second class, and need start it from first class (MainActivity), for this i make object of second class in first class. But i have an error.